# помогите с кодом , ошибка : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

Tags: java

Добрый день, есть код написаны на библиотек org.openqa.selenium. Выдаёт ошибку java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

код:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
public class seofast {
public static void main(String[] args){     
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_PATH_PROPERTY, "phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();   
    driver.get( "http://www.seo-fast.ru" );}
}
```

вот ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at seofast.main(seofast.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В classpath'е вашего приложения отсутствует необходимый JAR файл, содержащий класс `com.google.common.base.Function`

Answer (score 2):

Не смотря на то, что верхний ответ уже отмечен верным, могу заметить, что такое бывает не всегда. К примеру, если этот класс наследует от java.util.Function - аналог лямбды в 8 джавы, то java все равно скажет, что такого класса com/google/common/base/Function не существует.